# Find My Phone location on map never really works

Tags: 8.1, location-services, find-my-phone

I don't play around with this feature often, but I notice that my correct location is almost never on the Find My Phone page.  This could be a problem if I were ever to misplace my phone.

On the Find My Phone webpage, it usually says,

**Phone Location**: No Phone Found.

When I click the "Find My Phone" button again, it says:

**We're sorry, but we weren't able to find your phone. But please try again later. We might have a better connection in a little while.**

What is this "connection" they are talking about?  My connection is fine.  Is their connection somehow different?

There are two checkboxes: 1) always use push... and 2) save my phone's location periodically....

One the phone the the Find My Phone settings, there are two checkboxes.  These were initially unchecked. Eventually I tried checking them both and it made no difference.

Comment: When did you check them? It will take "a while" for the data to get updated

Comment: Just curious, did it ever update?  I just looked at mine.  It said it was in the street outside my office, so I think that's where it was the last time it transmitted it's location.

Comment: Eric, no, on the windows phone website, I still get the message "We're sorry, but we weren't able to find your phone...".  I see below it's working for you, so glad it's working for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone in

Settings > System > find my phone

The second setting is "Save my phone's location periodically."  I believe that's going to work off GPS, which needs a decent line of sight to the satellite in the sky.  So it's probably not going to work properly if haven't been outdoors since you turned on that setting.

My phone is currently in a desk drawer and when I try to find it, it says it's about a half mile away.  It might also be approximating my phone's location by triangulating off the cell phone towers.  The "ring my phone" works quite well if it's charged, even if the ringer is turned off.  I use it all the time.

Comment: There are two checkboxes: 1) always use push... and 2) save my phone's location periodically....  These were initially unchecked.  Eventually I tried checking them both and it made no difference.

Comment: I placed my comment in the body of the question as well.